# How to embed a pdf from an external site in HTML?

Tags: html, pdf

I want to embed a pdf from an external site (link to the pdf= http://flightaware.com/resources/airport/SAN/APD/AIRPORT+DIAGRAM/pdf) onto my website. How do I do this?

I've tried:

```
<iframe src="http://flightaware.com/resources/airport/SAN/APD/AIRPORT+DIAGRAM/pdf" width="500" height="700">
```

But it hasn't worked.

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The following works fine in chrome and firefox:

```
<html>
<body>
test
<iframe src="http://flightaware.com/resources/airport/SAN/APD/AIRPORT+DIAGRAM/pdf" width="500" height="700"></iframe>
</body>
</html>
```